# Unity3D EditorUserBuildSettings.architectureFlags not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to execute some pre-build code to instantiate a couple of objects from their prefabs through script. Since our team uses free version of unity, we want to create some objects through script for better version handling.

We try to use the code we found at http://jon-martin.com/?p=309 to do achieve this. This is pretty straight forward, but I'm having problems with the following part of the code:

```
BuildOptions customBuildOptions = EditorUserBuildSettings.architectureFlags;
```

I get the compiler error:

`'UnityEditor.EditorUserBuildSettings' does not contain a definition for 'architectureFlags'`

We're using Unity 4.1.5f1, and I suspect this might have changed. The BuildOptions are modified to enable BuildOptions.AutoRunPlayer and finally passed to BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer (as seen in the link above).

So, does anyone know how I can access the BuildOptions for the current build target settings and then modify them?

Comment: Is your script  in the Assets/Editor folder inside your project folder? (and UnityEditor namespace is included)

Answer (score 0):

That flag appears to have been removed from that object in 4.15.  But, some stuff has been added to Unity to enable Pre and Post processing of builds on Windows and Mac.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PostProcessSceneAttribute.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PostProcessBuildAttribute.html

I think you'd be able to do what you want using [PostProcessScene].

p.s. I'm not sure how much of the BuildPipeline stuff is available in the free version of Unity.  I thought it was one of the selling points of the Pro license.